# Arrival function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am struggling a lot with this assignment I am doing. I have been trying to do it for a few weeks and can't figure out how to make further progress on this. I need to make an arrival function for AI. I can't figure out what the equation is for distance in order to continue making this function. Here is what I have so far for it.

```
void Steering::Arrival( sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f target, float maxSpeed, float maxAcceleration, float timeToTarget, float slowRadius, float targetRadius, double distance, SteeringOutput& steering )
{
    timeToTarget = 0.1;

    steering.linear = target - position;
    MathHelper::Normalize( steering.linear );
    distance = 

    //Check if arrived at target
    if (timeToTarget < targetRadius)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Check if we are out of the slowRadius
    if (timeToTarget > slowRadius)
        target = maxSpeed;

}
```

It gets cut off there because I know I'm not doing something right, I just can't figure out what it is. I'm sure more information is needed to help me at all but I'm not sure what information is necessary so please just let me know what else is needed.

Comment: If you can write the assignment would be great.

Comment: What do you mean Robert?

Comment: Are you iterating over the distance or is this a one-time calculation?

Comment: How many dimensions in the distance?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  It has to just be the distance between the AI ship and the player's ship. I have a bunch of header and CPP files that I could add to the post.  I didn't originally because It would be really long and tiresome to get through.

Comment: Can we assume that `steering.linear` is a `sf::Vector2f`? With that, your normal distance equation is `a*a + b*b = c*c`, making `distance = sqrt(steering.linear.x*steering.linear.x + steering.linear.y*steering.linear.y)`.

Comment: That is exactly what steering.linear is.  I thought .x and .y should be in there when I was fiddling around with different things but it would give me an error.

Comment: Thank you OnlineCop.  I no longer have an error for distance equation.  Now I need to figure out what the targetSpeed is.